# Keyboard command/shortcut to resize window

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, gui

The bottom of my (Chromium) window is off the bottom of the screen.  If I move the window up, Unity maximises the window (which I do not want).

What key combination can I press to make the active window shorter (smaller)?

Comment: Have you tried to press `ctrl-alt-keypad 8` several times?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and press <kbd>space</kbd>.

Then press <kbd>R</kbd> on your keyboard. You can now use the arrows to resize the window.

Comment: it shows the arrow key to resize, but window is not resized. Should I press then another key to apply the change?

Answer (score 24):

You can press Alt + F8 and your mouse pointer will automatically switch to a resizing pointer, which you can use to resize your window either with the mouse or using the arrow keys.

You can then click or press esc to stop and turn your normal pointer back on.

Comment: Cool - though alt-F8 seems to only change window width

Comment: Alt F7 allow me to move the window around without it snapping onto the top bar.  That would've worked for me too.

Comment: It depends how you move your mouse after pressing F8. Horizontally → width, vertically → height, diagonally → both.

Comment: Right you are, htorque

Answer (score 20):

I tend to use <kbd>alt</kbd> + `middle-drag` to resize windows.

It's not pure keyboard but it is useful in awkward situations (like this)

Comment: You need to try this ~near the edges of the window.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you from 6 years in the future :)

Comment: It's `alt` + right-drag for me.

Answer (score 7):

I find <kbd>Alt</kbd> + **right-click** + **drag** to be the most convenient way to do this.

Answer (score 6):

As there is no mention of the shortcut using **super key** I will add it.
This is complete keyboard shortcut, which has a **super key**(key with windows symbol).
Just press <kbd>super key</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and then use arrow keys to resize the window. Arrow Up and Down keys maximize and minimize current window respectively.

Bonus Tip: Hold the <kbd>super key</kbd> and a short cut menu pops up with all possible short cuts.Tested on **ubuntu 14.04** and works on **16.04** also.

Comment: This answer is excellent.       Just note that 'super' + 'ctrl' + 'down' minimises the window.

Answer (score 5):

Right-click the title bar, select `Resize` and then control the window size with the mouse.

Comment: That works for decorated windows, but not for undecorated ones.

Comment: Use `Alt` + `Space` to make appear the list

Answer (score 0):

The combo is different in Ubuntu (Unity) and Kubuntu (KDE).

Ubuntu 16.04 defaults to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + **middle mouse button** and then **drag with mouse**.

Kubuntu with KDE 5.8 defaults to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + **right mouse button** and then **drag with mouse**.

Place mouse on one of the nine edges, and then drag in the direction you want to upsize or downsize.

Answer (score 0):

The resize window key combination for **LXDE** is:

Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and press <kbd>space</kbd>.

Then press <kbd>Z</kbd> on your keyboard. You can now use the arrows to resize the window. (If you have not pressed Alt-space this session, there might be a short delay of about half a second.)

(Pressing <kbd>R</kbd> will **R**oll Up/Down [minimise] the window.)

Click the mouse or press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to regain normal control of your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Resize a window by dragging the edges or corner of the window. Hold down Shift while resizing to snap the window to the edges of the screen and other windows. Move or resize a window using only the keyboard. Press **Alt** + **F7** to move a window or **Alt** + **F8** to resize.