# Adding customized window size on the terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I would like to add/modify custom size on the terminal

Right now I have these:

[image: example]

I would like to add my own personal window sizes, how can I do iT?

Comment: I doubt there's a simple way to do it. You can have different profiles with custom window size, and switch those, but adding another entry to the drop-down menu will probably require editing the source code of the gnome-terminal

Comment: Agree. If you really want to change the code than this would be a good startpoint `/usr/share/help/C/gnome-terminal/app-terminal-sizes.page` but be carefull. Alternatively you can set a shortcut/stroke with `xdotool getactivewindow windowsize 40% 40%` or make a use of this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/44698/keyboard-command-to-[resize-window

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new profile, and switch to the defined profile to change the window size. `Edit -> Preferences -> Profiles`.

EDIT: You can also try using the `--geometry` flag, see [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=804397&p=5023790#post5023790). Additonally, take a look at `gconf-editor`, you might find a way to configure it under "Apps".

Comment: If I am not wrong, the question was how to add a window size to the option list.

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04, and the resize menu has been moved to a sub-menu, and for the life of me, I can not figure how to trigger the keyboard shortcuts.

I now have the following aliases:

```
alias 132x24 'resize -s 24 132'
alias 132x43 'resize -s 43 132'
alias 80x24 'resize -s 24 80'
alias 80x43 'resize -s 43 80'
```

I subsequently switched to the Kubuntu desktop, and `gnome-terminal` works as it used to.