# Amplify the window's size

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

I can open a Terminal by pressing the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and subsequently maximize it with <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>.

I want to extend the window's size fractionally and tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> which simply amplifies the font size.

Rather than having to reach for the mouse and drag the window borders to resize, is there a way to do this using the keyboard, such as in with emacs C-x?

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44698/keyboard-command-shortcut-to-resize-window) works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with default system keyboard shortcuts.

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> (*Resize*) to start resizing a window. Use the <kbd>Arrow</kbd> keys to adjust the size and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when done.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (*Move*) to start moving a window. Use the <kbd>Arrow</kbd> keys to move the window and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when done. Try also <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> for quickly aligning with the screen edge or the border of another window.
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> (*Toggle Maximization State*) to maximize/unmaximize the window. This is equivalent to the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> shortcut.

These shortcut keys optionally can be changed in `Settings` - `Keyboard`

[image]